# jquery - selected text keeps being stored outputting duplicated text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to make a function to highlight text, then insert into a textarea only what's selected. It's working bar one thing: if I keep selecting text, then selecting something else, it will just add it all together and I can't figure out why.

code to get selected text (along with positioning)

```
// selected text
function getSelected() 
{
    var return_text = '';
    if (window.getSelection) 
    {
        return_text = window.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.getSelection) 
    {
        return_text = document.getSelection();
    }
    return return_text;
}
```

Then the code to show a box to insert that text into a textarea, making sure it only allows text from within a comment area...

```
var quote_box = $('#selective-quote');
$(document).on('mouseup', ".comment-body div", function(e) 
{
    if ($('#comment').length) // only do this if comment box exists (logged in)
    {
        var selection = getSelected();
        var selectedText = selection.toString();

        if (typeof selection !== undefined && selectedText.length > 0 && selection.anchorNode.nodeName == '#text')
        {
            var container = $(this);
            var r=selection.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
            var relative=document.body.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
            // show the quote button box
            quote_box.css('position','absolute');
            quote_box.css('top',r.bottom -relative.top - 45);
            quote_box.css('left',r.left);
            quote_box.css('height', 'auto');
            quote_box.show();

            var text_to_insert = '';
            $(document).on('click', "#insert-selective-quote", function(e)
            {
                var username = container.parent().parent().children('.comment-meta').find('.username').text();
                text_to_insert = '[quote='+username+']' + $.trim(selectedText) + '[/quote]';

                console.log(text_to_insert);

                var current_text = $('#comment').val();
            
                $('#comment').val(current_text + text_to_insert); 
                quote_box.hide();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            quote_box.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

So if I had text with "this comment here" and I repeatedly highlighted "here" say 4 times (clicking off it each time), it would store it 4 times...I'm so confused. So I click the insert button and then it inserts it 4 times. Why?

It's supposed to only insert what's highlighted there and then, nothing else. Not anything previously highlighted like it seems to do now.

Comment: So you just want to copy your selection??: https://jsfiddle.net/f8nsj7yt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the mouse button is released, you create a new click listener, since the creation of the click listener happens inside of the mouseup handler:

```js
$(document).on('mouseup', ".comment-body div", function(e) {
  /* ... */
  $(document).on('click', "#insert-selective-quote", function(e) {
    /* ... */
  })
  /* ... */
})
```

So, at the first mouseup event, the first click listener is installed. On the second mouseup event, the first click listener still exists (since it's never removed) and a second listener is installed as well, and so on.

So after 4 times, you already have 3 click listeners installed from before and install a 4th one. And on clicking the button, all the 4 listeners fire, since they all listen on the same event.

You should either install one listener globally, or remove the existing listener before installing a new one. You can remove any existing click listener using `$(document).off('click', '#insert-selective-quote')`, just add that before you do the `$(document).on('click', '#insert-selective-quote', ...)`.

Comment: "install one listener globally" how would I do this to prevent it like that? and for the other method, where would I put the "off" handler to test that way too?

Comment: Hm I guess in your code the easier way is probably to just remove the old listener before attaching a new one, because your code closes over several local variables in the outer scope (`selectedText`, `container`). With a global listener you would move the whole listener out of the mouseup handler and install it once, and refer to the `selectedText` and `container` by making those global instead or - to be less messy - by setting them as properties on the button itself using jQuery's `.data` and accessing those from inside the click handler.

Comment: Any examples of how to do this with my code then? I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: This will remove the previous handler before adding the new one...  $(document).off("click").on('click',...

Comment: No, this will remove _all_ click listeners on the document (also others')! You need to specify the same selector as when you installed it, like I showed. For example `$(document).off('click', '#insert-selective-quote').on('click', '#insert-selective-quote', ...)`